# set index action default action controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make index action is the default action in this controller when i write

> http//mydomain/action

call index action > http//mydomain/case-studies

will call index action

my problem when i write the url gives me this message  `The resource cannot be found.`
the url i write it `http//mydomain/case-studies`it should be call index action but `The resource cannot be found.`

This is the controller

```
 [RoutePrefix("case-studies")]
public class case_studiesController : Controller
{
    // GET: CaseStudies
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View("/views/case-studies/Index.cshtml");
    }

    [Route("adaep")]
    public ActionResult adaep()
    {
        return View("/views/case-studies/pagename.cshtml");
    }
}
```

this is my route

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer worked with me to keep home route as default and make default action for every controller i changed this from  [Route("Index")] to  [Route("")] with the same route

```
      [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View("/views/case-studies/Index.cshtml");
    }

 public class RouteConfig
{
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =    UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

   }
}
```

That route does that.the definition of the route is: if {controller} is empty use "Home" if {action} is empty use "index" if {id} has value place in the id parameter. for every url that has only the controller name, the request should go the index action

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional     }
```

);

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `MapRoute` is incorrect you're `MapRoute` is having a default controller of *Home*:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

change it to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "case-studies", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: No the first route for home  page i can not change i want to set default action to another controller i solved it already i will write the solution that work with me for this issue